# Asynchronous execution of a loop: how to make it synchronous

Tags: spring, spring-boot

**spring-boot-starter-parent 3.0.0**

It may be important. Anyway, under the hood:
**<spring-framework.version>6.0.2</spring-framework.version>**

```
import lombok.Synchronized;
...

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RequestService {

    @Synchronized
    public void scrape() {
        List<SiteEntity> sites = siteRepository.findAllByActiveTrue();
        System.out.println("Method: The Thread name is " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
​
​
        for (SiteEntity site : sites) {
            System.out.println("Site: " + site.getUrl());
​
            System.out.println("Outer: The Thread name is " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
​
            List<PhraseEntity> phrases = phraseRepository.findAllActivePhrasesBySite(site.getId());
            assertSameSite(phrases, site);
​
            final int CHUNK = 10;
            List<List<PhraseEntity>> phraseChunks = Lists.partition(phrases, CHUNK);
​
            for (List<PhraseEntity> chunk : phraseChunks) {
​
                System.out.println("Inner: The Thread name is " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
​
                System.out.println(chunk.get(0).getPhrase() + " : " + chunk.get(chunk.size() - 1).getPhrase());
                Document doc = sendRequest(chunk, 0);
​
                saveManager.save(doc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The service is scraping positions of a web site in a search engine.

For debug purpose I have input each site 100 phrases. That totals to 200 phrases.

This loop can change sites arbitrarily. And the total amount of results can be like 380 (despite the fact that the total amount of phrases is 200).

The reason of that is asynchronicity. I print the names of threads. They change.

Lombok's @Synchronized has not helped

**Questions:**

1. Am I right that Spring is asynchronous by default? Documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.task-execution-and-scheduling
2. How can I execute this loop synchronously?

Comment: 1. No, 2. it should be sync already. So something else in your code must use threads somewhere (probably your HTTP library).

Comment: @Kifsif, just how do the names of threads change? I'd expect to see only the name for the main application thread because that's where you're printing it from.